# Trying to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, cannot compile procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Trying to write a procedure which takes no values in, adds a sale price column to my existing product table, then loops through to calculate a sale price and insert that into the new column.

I haven't been able to get anything to work, I think it's something to do with Oracle not liking `ALTER TABLE` to be run from inside a procedure, but I don't know, and I don't know enough to direct my attempts anywhere else.

This is my attempt

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale as
BEGIN
    DECLARE
       NewSalePrice NUMBER(6,2):=0; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter table ' || Product || 'add or replace column' || 'SalePrice NUMBER(6,2);'
    FOR p in (SELECT ProductStandardPrice FROM Product
            group by ProductStandardPrice)
        LOOP
            CASE WHEN p.ProductStandardPrice>=400 THEN NewSalePrice:=.9*price
                 WHEN p.ProductStandardPrice<400 THEN NewSalePrice:=.85*price
            INSERT INTO Product(SalePrice)
            VALUES(NewSalePrice)
        END LOOP;
END ProductLineSale
```

Product is the literal name of the Product table in my database. SalePrice is what I would like the new column to be named.

SQLDeveloper won't compile the procedure. The error I get is fairly cryptic as well:

> Error(2,10): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     constant exception      table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar.

Comment: I don't think that the issue is with `ALTER TABLE`, as there is no `=` in that statement. Look immediately above there, where there is an equals sign. Why do you need to `ALTER TABLE` at all in a stored procedure, though? That should be a one-off operation that you would do outside the stored procedure, not something that has to happen every time the stored procedure is executed. I also don't see any need for you to be using string concatenation at all, as your product table name will never change, so it can be hard-coded directly into the SQL itself. I think this is an XY problem.

Comment: I agree that placing ALTER TABLE inside a procedure is bad form.....however this is an assignment for class and one of the stipulations for our function/procedure is that it adds the new column as part of its operation. This same teacher stipulates that we comment every SQL command we run. I'm certainly in a bit over my head with this task, but SQL seems like a language that documents itself very well when it comes to simple stuff like creating tables and inserting values into rows.

Comment: Honestly I don't know what sql developer thinks the issue is. I have tried variations of the above incantation, sql developer moves the red error line around, but the compiler spits out the same error message. Every example I can find on various websites uses the = sign as I am as well so I dunno.

Comment: Do they use `:=` in a `DECLARE` statement, though? And did you check the Oracle documentation for the proper syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a host of errors...  The ones that jump out at me on a first pass.

- The requirement doesn't make sense.  Adding a column in a procedure doesn't make sense.  You create a procedure because you want code to be reusable.  Adding a column can only be done once, hence it is by definition not reusable.
- A procedure has to be compiled before it can be executed.  If there is a reference to a column that doesn't exist, the procedure will fail to compile.  Thus, if you want to add a column to the table using dynamic SQL, all subsequent references to the column (i.e. your `insert` statement) would need to use dynamic SQL as well.
- Your DDL statement is incorrect.  There is no `add or replace` clause, it's `alter table product add SalePrice NUMBER(6,2)`.  Note that when you're building your string, you also have to ensure that there is a space between the clause `add` and the column name `SalesPrice`-- one of the two strings you're concatenating together would need that.
- It doesn't make sense to have a `declare` where you do.  You can declare variables between the `as` and the `begin` one line above.  You are allowed to create a nested PL/SQL block there with the `declare` but then you'd need a matching `begin` and `end` that you don't have.
- If you're going to use a `case` statement in PL/SQL, you'd need an `end case`.  You would also need to have a semicolon `;` after each expression.
- Your `insert` statement is also missing a semicolon.
- Logically, I am hard pressed to imagine that you really want have an `insert` here.  It doesn't make logical sense to create a bunch of new rows in the table when you add a new column.  I would assume that you want to `update` the value of the new column in existing rows.  Which, presumably, requires that your cursor selects the primary key column(s) and potentially changes whether and what you're grouping by.
- `Product` and `price` are being used as local variables in the `execute immediate` statement and in the `case` statement but aren't defined.  I'm guessing that you just want to hard code the name of the table you're altering and that `price` is supposed to reference the name of a column in the table that you need to select in your cursor but I'm not sure.

This `case` statement is syntactically valid (or would be if `price` resolves to something valid).  Many of the other corrections are less obvious because of the reasons I detailed above.

```
case when p.ProductStandardPrice>=400 
     then NewSalePrice:=.9*price;
     when p.ProductStandardPrice<400 
     THEN NewSalePrice:=.85*price;
  end case;
```

If I was to speculate at what you actually want (given that this is a homework assignment with requirements that don't actually make sense), I'd guess something like

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale 
as
begin
  execute immediate 'alter table Product add SalePrice NUMBER(6,2)';
  execute immediate 'update product ' ||
                    '   set SalePrice = (case when ProductStandardPrice >= 400 ' ||
                    '                         then 0.9 * Price ' ||
                    '                         else 0.85 * Price ' ||
                    '                      end) ';
end ProductLineSale;
```

If you're going to use dynamic SQL, it almost always makes sense to declare a local variable, build the SQL statement in that variable, and then execute it so that you can debug things by printing out the statement you've build to debug it.